# Android dynamically add a menu item based on DB field

Tags: android, android-listview, android-menu

I'm trying to show an extra menu item (contextual action bar) when the user selects one/multiple items in a `ListView`. Basically I'm checking if the selected item has a field in the DB set to true. If so, I add the extra menu item.

I tried to query the DB for the selected item in `onItemCheckedStateChanged()` and invalidate the menu. This will call `onPrepareActionMode()` where I could show the extra option if needed.

This does not work because the options that are already selected with the DB column set to true, are not remembered when an item with the special DB column set to false gets selected in `onItemCheckedStateChanged()` and when `onPrepareActionMode()` gets called the extra menu item is removed.

How can I approach this better? Essentially I need a way to remember all the selected `ListView` items that have the extra field in the DB set to true so I can show the extra menu item - and vice-versa remove the item when none of the selected `ListView` items has that DB field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to decide how to handle a situation when both kind of items are selected at once (say, one with `true` in db and one with `false`). If you decide to allow it, track your button state somewhere in your activity. I'd add a private integer member to your activity and increase this number whenever the item with `true` in the database is selected and decrease it whenever such item is deselected. If it's zero in `onPrepareActionMode` - don't show your button.

Comment: I was thinking of something similar using the ids of the fields set to `true` but this is much better. Thank you Vladimir :).                                                                                                                                     To those who might find this question useful, don't forget to set the counter to 0 when the CAB is destroyed otherwise if the user selects an item with the DB field set to `true` and pressed the back button the counter will start from 1 on the next select.